# table-layout: fixed css not working properly with given column's width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my table structure

```
<table id="recordingsTable" style="width:900px" class="tablesorter fixed_table">
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed_table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

populating table from js:

```
str = ''
str += '<thead>'
str += '<tr>' +
    '<th style="width:150px;text-align:left !important;border-left:0;">Col 1</th>' +
    '<th style="width:150px;text-align:center !important">Col 2</th>' +
    '<th style="width:300px;text-align: center !important;">Col 3</th>' +
    '<th style="width:100px;text-align: center !important;">Col 4</th>' +
    '<th style="width:100px;text-align: center !important;">Col 5</th>' +
    '<th style="width:100px;text-align: center !important;">Col 6</th>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</thead><tbody style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;">';


    for(i=0; i < recording_object.length; i++) {
        str += '<tr>';
        str += '<td style="text-align:left !important; padding-left:8px;border-left:0;">'
        str += recording_object[i].text
        str += '</td>' 
        str += '<td class="s3_file_path">' + recording_object[i].path + '</td>'
        str += '<td class="s3_file_name" style="font-size:11px;">' + recording_object[i].file_name + '</td>'
        str += '<td>' + recording_object[i].number + '</td>'
        str += '<td>';
        str += '<button id="' + recording_object[i].id + '" onclick="dup_dialog(this)" type="button" data-toggle="modal" ' +
            'data-target="#upload-all-modal" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Duplicate</button>' +
            '</td>'
        str += "<td>";
        str += '<button id="' + recording_object[i].id + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" ' +
            'disabled="disabled" data-target="#association">Association</button>'
        str += '</td></tr>'
    }
    str += '</tbody>'
```

but it not showing table column's width as defined in js, and when i change any column width it doesn't change in view; even when i change it by inspecting element

it seems that table-layout not working properly as it should assign each column width as given. can anyone help?

Here is table screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Could you post the rendered html please

Answer (score 0):

All i see is a problem with `thead`.You forget to open it.I put some random data.I also removed the paddings in your cells.The width is exactly as you specify it in javascript.Check the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ks3mj4ec/4/

Comment: thead is added i missed it here. i will update my question

Comment: the width is exactly as you specify it in the fiddle.Col 3 has width 300px,Col 5 100px etc.So you must have other css rules too that cause the problem because for me is working as expected...